# On the definition of Open set

Tags: general-topology

The book I'm reading defines an open as the set that can be written in the form:

**Definition 1**:
$E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) \gt 0\}$

with $f:\mathbb{R}^2  \mapsto\mathbb{R}^2  $ definite and continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2 $

why can't $f$ also be negative in the open set? Couldn't an open set be the union of all intervals in which $f\ge 0$ and $f\le 0$?

It also says that this definition is equivalent to :

**Definition 2**:
"E is an open set if for each p belonging to E, there exists an $r\gt 0$ such that $d(p,q) \lt r$, for all $q \in E$".

And that can be proven that a set is open by definition 2) only if it is open by definition 1)

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: I think the book is trying to give an equivalent definition of an open set. This defintion agrees with the usual definition and you can do this in any metric space.

Answer (score 2):

Any open set $U$ can be written in the form $U=\{(x,y): f(x,y) >0\}$ for some continuous function $f$. To prove this define $f(x,y)=d((x,y), U^{c})$. [ In a metric space $d(x,A)$ stands for $\inf \{d(x,a):a \in A\}$].  [You can also write $U=\{(x,y): g(x,y) <0\}$ for some continuous function $g$].

Hence the definition in the book is equivalent to the usual definition of open sets.

Comment: How is $U^c$ defined ?

Comment: @GiulianoMalatesta It is the complement of $U$.

Comment: Kavi.$U^c$ is the complement $ U=U_f$ (depends on f, so does $U^c_f$. Now you define $f$ in terms of $U^c_f$, circular? Is this ok?Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I think the point of confusion of OP and you is you are starting with $f$. The book is saying that for every $U$ there is an $f$. In fact in any metric space a set $U$ is open iff $U=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ for some conti uous function $f$ depending on $U$. The book is using this fact to give its own (equivalent) definition of an open set.

Comment: Kavi.Thanks.1) If $U_f:=${$(x,y)| f(x,y) >0, f$ cont} then U_f is open.Fine.Now 2) U is open, given, how do you find f such that $U_f=U$ ?The way you define f looks a bit circular (?)Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas What we are doing here is to prove the equivalence of the two definitions. I am assuming that $U$ is open in the usual sense and trying to prove that it is $U_f$ for some $f$. There is no circularity in this argument.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy. Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly the function you defined gives the distance between a point (x,y) in the open set and a point in the complementary of the open set? And the fact that it must be always positive is thus due to the fact that the two points cannot be not the same because they are not in the same set (one in $U$ and the other in $U^c$ ?

Comment: Yes, $U^{c}$ is a closed set in the usual sense we cannot have a point outside this set which has distance $0$ from it.